# Foundry Anvil (local test network) database

Tags: ganache, testnets, foundry, database, anvil

I am using the Foundray Anvil local network to test my application. Is there an option while initiating the test network to store data of blockchain in a specific location? Similar to this `--db /my/path/to/database` in ganache-cli

Answer (score 0):

Yes, found it `--dump-state /my/path/to/database`